# Wrapping an array of small cylinders around a large cylinder

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have an array of small cylinders that I would like to wrap around a larger cylinder. Before wrapping, the array looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, I would like each cylinder within the array (and the array itself) to follow the contour of the outer cylinder.

I've tried the Shrinkwrap modifier (and placing it as both first and last in the Modifiers list), and setting the Target to the large cylinder.

Within the shrinkwrap modifier, I've tried setting Wrap Method to Project, and I've tried setting Snap Mode to Outside, On Surface, and Outside surface. I've also tried messing with the Offset.

Comment: it won't work this way but you can use another method to make your array circular, like give it a Simple Deform/Bend

Comment: … or use a Lattice to deform the cylinders and shrinkwrap the lattice to the surface.

Comment: ... or a curve modifier after the array modifier where the curve is circle of radius of big cilinder + radius of small. (or the

Answer (score 7):

'Borrow' a latitude from your tube. If there isn't one, you can cut it.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> Duplicate a latitude of your tube
- <kbd>P</kbd> separate it to a new object
- Convert it to a curve
- It may be smoother if you convert the curve's Spline Type to Bezier, and its handles to 'Automatic'.
- You may want to scale the curve slightly outwards, if you want your cylinders on the tube's surface

Assuming your small cylinder is sufficiently subdivided along its length to deform..

[image]

Give it an *Array* and *Curve* modifier, aimed at your latitude-curve.

Comment: Doh, too Slow. .Was looking at shrinkwrapping circle to big cylinder and off setting by little cyl radius. Much the same tho.

Comment: @batFINGER I went for this way because it's more general? .. tree trunks, winding staircases, wounded knees... not everything can be shrunk to :)